# Find the arc length $\int_ 0 ^{4\pi} r(t)=3\cos ti+4\sin tkj+tk$

Tags: calculus, special-functions, trigonometric-integrals, arc-length, elliptic-integrals

So my components are $$f(x)= 3\cos t, \ \text g(y)=4\sin t ,\ \text h(z)= t$$

$$f'(x)=-3\sin t, \ \text g'(y)=4\cos t,\ \text h'(z)=1$$

I found the derivatives of each component and plugin to the arc length and have this

$$\int_ 0 ^{4\pi} \sqrt{9\sin^2t+16\cos^2t+1} dt $$

After this I'm stuck. I saw examples on YouTube where they used trig identities $$\sin^2t + \cos^2t = 1$$ but the coefficient are not the same so I'm not able to factor out the coefficient so what now? Please help.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: The answer involves [Elliptic Integral functions](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral).

Comment: Unless you are expected to evaluate this as an elliptic integral (for example, if that is what the previous material was about), then leave it in the form $$\int_ 0 ^{4\pi} \sqrt{9\sin^2t+16\cos^2t+1} \;dt$$

Answer (score 1):

the integral $$\int_ 0 ^{4\pi} \sqrt{9\sin^2t+16\cos^2t+1} dt $$ can be rewrited as $$\int_ 0 ^{4\pi} \sqrt{17-7\sin^2t} dt $$ and then you factor out the sqrt17 leaving you with :

$$\int_ 0 ^{4\pi} \sqrt{17}\sqrt{1-(7/17)\sin^2t} dt $$ which is a special integral, an incomplete elliptic integral of the second kind, which result is given by 8sqrt(17)E(7/17)

you can find more about these types of integrals and how to solve them here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Incomplete_elliptic_integral_of_the_second_kind

Answer (score 0):

Actually the integral
$$
\int_0^{4\pi} \sqrt{9\sin^2t+16\cos^2t+1} dt 
=
8\int_0^{\pi/2} \sqrt{9\sin^2t+16\cos^2t+1} dt 
$$
cannot be solved by elementary methods. The [answer](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%24%24+%5Cint_0%5E%7B4%5Cpi%7D+%5Csqrt%7B9%5Csin%5E2t%2B16%5Ccos%5E2t%2B1%7D+dt++%24%24)
involves elliptic integrals of the second kind:

In other words let $$
E(k)=\int_0^{\pi/2}\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2 x}dx
$$
and solve it in terms of $E$. You can use $16\cos^2t=16(1-\sin^2t)$ to get started.